# Automatically insert WordPress custom field

Tags: wordpress, meta

I want to add a new custom field with a meta key and meta value to my posts.

Currently the only way it is added to a post is if I go into the post and click Update.
I have lots of posts and essentially want this custom field to be added to all posts automatically with an assigned meta value.

This meta value  is different for each post.

Comment: Please, explain better your problem? Which meta value do you want to insert ? It's something that can be calculated automatically?

Comment: I'm just inserting a string of text into the custom field. This text is different for each post. Users cannot edit this custom field. The reason why I'm inserting text into a post via a custom field is it's searchable with the search system I'm using. I just want to mass update all posts (or to be more accurate a custom post type I've created) so the custom field is inserted into all posts without having to update/save each existing post manually.

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this? I need this too and possibly something automated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I found this helpful: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/wordpress-how-to-insert-data-programmatically

```
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {
global $wpdb;
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
    add_post_meta($post_ID, 'field-name', 'custom value', true);
}
}
add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
```

This will add a 'custom value' to the 'field-name' in the $post_ID.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right method is using the 'save_post'hook,such as:

```
  function cwp_add_custom_post_meta($post_id, $post){
global $wpdb;
$post_cat_id=get_the_terms( $post_id, 'category' );
$post_cat_id=cwp_object_to_array($post_cat_id);
$post_cat_id=$post_cat_id['0'] ["term_id"];
$display_voting = get_tax_meta($post_cat_id,'cwp_display_voting');
if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
    update_post_meta($post_id,'display_voting', $display_voting);
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'cwp_add_custom_post_meta', 10, 2 );
```